# call to web api with string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api where I have 2 methods, one without parameter and two with different types of parameter (string and int). When calling the string method it doesnt work...what am I missing here?

```
public class MyControllerController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetInt(int id)
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetString(string test)
    {
        return Ok("it worked");
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My Call:

> /api/MyController/MyString //Doesnt work
>
> /api/MyController/1 //work

I get following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetInt(Int32)' in 'TestAngular.Controllers.MyControllerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

What am I missing in my request?

Comment: You don't need the `WebMethod` attribute for WebAPI

Comment: You cannot use the same route for two different endpoint. The methode GetInt wins and will use for both requests.

Comment: How is the way to do it? add {action} in routeTemplate?

Comment: Set `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and see my answer

Comment: Is that the only option I have ?

Comment: I prefer this variant. But you can try a solution with attributes: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change your uri's

```
/api/MyController

/api/MyController/string 

/api/MyController/1
```

You don't have to specify the methods.

You could take look at this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) on asp.net for further clarification.

Comment: I tried to follow that tutorial and apply on my project but I didn't get to work..So thats why I'm asking here, I must have missed something

Comment: @emptyman so did you try to call these uri's and you didn't get any response?

Comment: I got the int to work, but how do I send a string parameter? It cant find the method (it looks for the int)

Comment: I don't think that you need any extra work. You simply have to make a get request to this `/api/MyController/yourstringvalue`

Comment: I've updated my question..Now the int method works fine (after tuning from your tutorial). But I can't get my string to work

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution:
without changing default route in webapiconfig.cs file

add just a route to your string function:

```
[Route("Api/MyController/GetString/{test}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetString(string test)
```

http://localhost:49609/api/MyController/GetString/stringtest

Answer (score 8):

Also this uri's should work:

```
api/MyController/GetAll
api/MyController/GetString?param=string
api/MyController/GetInt?param=1
```

I think this is much clearer and should always work.
You use the routing behavior.

See here: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since you posted this, but I think I have the answer.
First off, there are two issues. First, as Pinback noted, you can't use the same route for two different endpoints.

However if you just eliminate the `int` method, you'll still run into the problem.
Remember: the default route looks like this: api/{controller}/{id}
In order to bind the parameter, it has to be called "id", and not "test".

Change the signature to this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetString(string id)
```

and it will work. 
(you can also change `{id}` to `{test}` in the webapiconfig.cs file).

Answer (score 0):

You can also take string parameter in body

```
string body;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
body = sr.ReadToEnd();
```