# Set Route Attribute with a String Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to create a Web API method with a custom route that takes in a String parameter, but this appears to error upon application start - so I don't even need to hit the route or the method for the application to break.

```
// Pass String to TMS and Return an ID
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/job/import/{import:string}")]
public int TmsImport(string import)
{
    var TmsId = 0;
    if (import.Length > 0)
    {
        TmsId = 1;
    }
    return (TmsId);
}
```

The application breaks on the following method in Global.asx:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

This same method works when I pass an int to the method, but it doesn't seems to able to recognise the name 'string' in the parameter. I did see an answer to a similar question here: [call to web api with string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798836/call-to-web-api-with-string-parameter) - but I can't figure out where the change would be from that answer?  If it would be in the call from the JS or in the route config?

Comment: Just remove `:string` from `{import:string}` and try to connect to "api/job/import/somestring"

Comment: That worked thanks :)

Comment: I will post this as an answer if you don't mind

Comment: Yeah go ahead I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove `:string` from `{import:string}`and try to connect to

> "api/job/import/somestring"

[MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) on web-api routing may also be useful to learn why this works.